# Localize text using Resources on Asp.Net WebForms in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, resources

I have ASP.NET WebForms application c# based.

I have ImageButton

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="divSection_btnAdd" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="return  TConfirm(this,'<%$Resources:Resource, Confirm%>')"/>
```

**Problem:**
dont show resource value but show '<%$Resources:Resource, Confirm%>'

> Resources:Resource.Confirm = 'Are you sure to delete this item?'

how to show resource key value?

Answer (score 2):

please use :

1-in page code behind c#:

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.Render(hWriter);
        writer.Write(this.Localize(sb.ToString()));
    }
 private const string ResourceFileName = "Resource";
    private string Localize(string html)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = new Regex(@"Localize\(([^\))]*)\)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled).Matches(html);
        foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches)
        {
            html = html.Replace(match.Value, GetGlobalResourceObject(ResourceFileName, match.Groups[1].Value).ToString());
        }
        return html;
    }
```

**edit ImageButton:**

```
<asp:ImageButton 
    ID="divSection_btnAdd" 
    runat="server"     
    OnClientClick="return  TConfirm(this,'Localize(Confirm)')"/>
```